# Getting error while applying color to Flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

I'm new to Flutter and Dart. I'm not sure why I'm getting this syntax error while applying color to the Text widget using ThemeData.[image]

Below are the details of my Flutter and Dart:

```
Flutter 2.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 02c026b03c (3 weeks ago) • 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
Engine • revision 0fdb562ac8
Tools • Dart 2.13.1
```

Comment: Try `...color.withOpacity(.6)` : `opacity` is a property of `Color` class. `withOpacity()` is a method.

Comment: Thank you so much Simon Sot this worked completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1.color.withOpacity(0.6)